# Is there a name for a "coordinate system" whose $x$-axis is centered at $x=1$ and $x=0$ is situated where negative infinity should be?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, coordinate-systems

I had an idea that what if the Cartesian coordinate system is modified so that the origin is at $x=1$, the right side goes to infinity as usual, while the left side goes to 0 as opposed to negative infinity, so that the entire domain the $x$-axis can cover is $(0,\infty)$. I don't know if this qualifies as a coordinate system (or what its technical definition is, in fact I don't know much about maths; I just suddenly thought about this today), but I gave it a try. I thought of something like this, with $1$ at the center, $2,3,4,...$ on the right while $1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ...$ on the left.

[image: a sketch of the coordinate system]

I tried to sketch some functions in this system and I find it interesting. I concluded that to graph the function in this "coordinate system" I can graph the following piece-wise function with $f(x)$ being the original function:

> $$f \left(\frac{1}{1-x} \right),\;x<0$$
>   $$f(x+1),\; x \geq0$$

And then pretend that the origin is $(1,0)$ and $-1$ on $x$-axis is actually $x=1/2$ while $1$ is actually $x=2$. The resulting curves are smooth ([for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztcER.png)) if the functions themselves are differentiable, which are conspicuous but I nonetheless tried to [prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGrCy.jpg) with my very limited calculus knowledge that the graph is smooth at $y$-intercept since I did not immediately realize the conspicuous fact that I am merely stretching the interval $(0,1)$.

But I did find that this "coordinate system" might have some use as it is demonstrative of the behaviors of certain functions who have asymptotes at $0$. For the reciprocal functions, [it visually shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKkCx.png) their linear $(1/x)$, quadratic $(1/x^2)$, quartic $(1/x^3)$, etc.. properties (as displayed on the left of $y$-axis), which are easy to relate when thinking about this functions but are not so easy to see from just looking at the [regular Cartesian graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc1VI.png). It is also good for [visualizing the reciprocal relationships of $x^n$ and $x^{-n}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EHgp.png), which is also quite hard to see in normal Cartesian graph. It also [visualizes the origin symmetry of logarithmic functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNAkp.png), which are easy to relate to when thinking about numerical log operations while hard to see from Cartesian graph.

Note: the shown $x$-axes in the pictures are invalid when viewing the graphs graphed in this "coordinate system" (if you may call it) and the $x$-axis should actually go like $1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1, $ (origin), $2, 3, 4,...$

I realized this might actually be a thing so I was wondering is this kind of "coordinate system" or transformation documented anywhere and have a name or is it just too trivial?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a 1D version of the Bloch sphere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere.

Comment: If you have values in the range  $(0, \infty)$ then you could plot them at $log(x)$ and get that effect.  Log based graphs are very common.

Comment: It looks like the axis is log(x).

Comment: Oh right!! It's a log based graph, how could I not have noticed that. Thanks!!

Comment: Your illustrations are not quite $\log$ based, but if you actually want something that is, it will have equal spacing between $\ldots, \frac18,\frac14,\frac12,1,2,4,8,\ldots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this coordinate system has not before been studied in-depth, and so doesn't have a name. But it's not *trivial* as you say. That's not the right word. It's just very *specific* or *particular*.

---

<sup>I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur have something to vote on, and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). If however anyone has an affirmative response to the question, please downvote this and post yours.</sup>